# Java find the index of string based on the utf-8 encoding index

Tags: java, string, encoding, java-8, byte

Consider the following string:

```
String text="un’accogliente villa del.";
```

I have the begin index of word "`accogliente`" which is `5`. But it is pre calculated based on `utf-8` encoding.

I want the exact index of the word , which is `3` as output. ie, I want to get 3 as output from 5. What is the best way of calculating it?

Comment: If i understood you correctly, why did you not use `indexOf`, which is correctly giving 3?

Comment: `"un'accogliente villa del.".indexOf("accogliente") == 3`

Comment: I have edited the question. I dont have the word accogliente. I only have the sentence and index of utf-8 , ie,5 . from that values i need to find 3. @Eugene

Comment: I have edited the question. I dont have the word accogliente. I only have the sentence and index of utf-8 , ie,5 . from that values i need to find 3. @Glains

Comment: so you have the sentence and an startIndex = 5. you want to get the index where the word containing that startIndex (`5`) is positioned?

Comment: I found similar problem question - maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317606/java-substring-broken-encoding

Comment: *I have the begin index of word "accogliente" which is 5* what is this suppose to mean? voting to close as unclear...

Comment: @Eugene so you have the sentence and an startIndex = 5. you want to get the index where the word containing that startIndex (5) is positioned? // yes. exactly.

Answer (score 3):

```
String text = "un’accogliente villa del."; // Unicode text
text = Normalizer.normalize(text, Form.NFC); // Normalize text

byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Index 5 UTF-8; 1 byte
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();                    // Index 3 UTF-16; 2 bytes (indexOf)
int[] codePoints = text.codePoints().toArray();       // Index 3 UTF-32; 4 bytes

int charIndex = text.indexOf("accogliente");
int codePointIndex = (int) text.substring(0, charIndex).codePoints().count();
int byteIndex = text.substring(0, charIndex).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
```

UTF-32 is the Unicode *code points*, the numbering of all symbols with **U+*XXXX*** where there maybe more (or less) than 4 hexadecimal digits.

Text normalisation is needed as `é` could be one code point, or two code points, a zero-width `´` followed by a `e`.

The question of UTF-8 byte index to UTF-16 char index:

```
int charIndex = new String(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                           0, byteIndex, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length();
```

Comment: @JoopEggen it seems the requirement is bit different for OP, he/she has a `startIndex = 5`, he has to find the word (first I assume) containing this letter, then stripping non-ascii letters find the index that word is at. I *think* this is what he needs

Comment: @TweetMan Sorry typo, `java.text.Normalizer` and `java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFKC`; for the question normalisation of text is not really needed.

Comment: @Eugene his mention of UTF-8 seems to indicate that 5 is the byte index of `acco`. Especially as the special quote U+2019 indeed is 3 bytes long in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will return output as `3` am i missing something in your question?

```
String text="un’accogliente villa del.";
text.indexOf("accogliente");
```

Comment: OP explained that this is not what he is looking for.

Comment: Yeah..got it ! @Glains

Answer (score 1):

Well assuming that this `startIndex` can only be a letter (ASCII one), you could do:

```
String text = "un’accogliente villa del.";
char c = text.charAt(5);
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
normalized = normalized.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", " ");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}*?" + c + "\\p{L}*?[$|\\s]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(normalized);

if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.start(0));
}
```